# selectInput() not passing anything to selected_data() (R shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I am working on R shiny app. Please note that I am trying to load data from my mysql server. So I used help of RMySQL package.

In my ui.R file, I have this:

```
selectInput("pitchername","Pitcher Name:", choices = unique(pitcher_names$pitcher_name), selected = "Chan Ho Park"),
```

I have csv file which was loaded onto 'pitcher_names' and it gives the list of names. In drop down menu, I have list of names to choose from.

In my server.R file, I have this:

```
selected_data <- reactive({

query <- dbSendQuery(conn = con, statement = paste('SELECT * FROM pitch_velo WHERE pitcher_name = ', "\"",input$pitchername,"\"",';',sep=''))
pitch_data <- dbFetch(query,n=-1)

minyear <- input$year[1]
maxyear <- input$year[2]

velo <- pitch_data %>% group_by(pitcher_name, pitch_type, Year) %>% summarise(velocity = mean(start_speed)) %>% arrange(velocity) %>% dplyr::filter(pitcher_name %in% input$pitcher_name) %>% dplyr::arrange(pitcher_name) %>% dplyr::filter(Year >= minyear) %>% dplyr::filter(Year <= maxyear) %>% dplyr::filter(pitch_type %in% input$pitch_type)
print(velo)
```

})

After working on this for half day, I realized that only problem is that name of pitcher chosen from selectInput() is not being passed onto dbSendQuery function in server.R. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in :

```
filter(pitcher_name %in% input$pitcher_name)
```

shouldn't it be:

```
filter(pitcher_name %in% input$pitchername)
```

And actually, I don't see the point of filtering your result query since you already put the condition in the query.

Comment: Made no difference

Comment: That corrected some of problem I was having. Thanks